# Get data by month which has data type as nvarchar

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried getting data by day, but not getting by month and year.

Need to retrieve data by month and year which has nvarchar datatype.

```
Select * from tbl_Details WHERE  CONVERT(varchar(2), date, 101) =  '02'
```

**Edit:**

The `date` is in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. The sample date is `24/02/2016`

Comment: so the date column is stored as nvarchar in the tbl_Details table?

Comment: yes. don't store dates in varchar columns. use proper data types.

Comment: yes it is right but, i need to retrive the data by nvrachar datatype only

Comment: yes date column is stored as nvarchar in the tbl_Details

Comment: You should start with the [ISDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function to figure out which rows contain "dates" that aren't really dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best solution, but one of the way to achieve your result.

First of all, [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186724.aspx) is the reserved keyword, so don't use it, try with some other name.

If your date field is in the VARCHAR, you can check the condition by [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188006.aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl_Details WHERE PARSENAME(REPLACE(SampleDate, '-', '.'), 2) = '02';
```

---

Sample execution for the same:

```
DECLARE @tbl_Details TABLE (SampleDate VARCHAR (20));

INSERT INTO @tbl_Details (SampleDate) VALUES
('2016-06-27'), ('2016-02-27'), ('2016-05-27'), ('2016-02-12');

SELECT *
FROM @tbl_Details 
WHERE PARSENAME(REPLACE(SampleDate, '-', '.'), 2) = '02';
```

If the date format is stored in this format of `2016/02/27`, in the replace function use `'/'` instead of `'-'` in the query above.

---

**Update:**

The OP has the `date` in the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, so the below query worked in his case:

```
SELECT *
FROM @tbl_Details 
WHERE PARSENAME(REPLACE(SampleDate, '/', '.'), 2) = '02'
      AND PARSENAME(REPLACE(SampleDate, '/', '.'), 1) = '2016';
```

Comment: @KhodayAnvesh: Updated in the end of the answer for the Year filter.

Comment: Though this works but it's kind of non recommended way. Rather, you should always make sure 1. storing datetime value in a datetime column 2. valid datetime values only present (validation from your application end)

Comment: I can get the data by month but not by year

Comment: Can you share a sample data of your `date` field? it is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: @KhodayAnvesh: For your format, for year comparision you need `PARSENAME(REPLACE(SampleDate, '/', '.'), 1) = '2016'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to `DATETIME` first and then can use `MONTH()` function for that purpose like

```
select * 
from tbl_Details 
WHERE MONTH(CONVERT(Date, [date], 120)) = 2;
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @KhodayAnvesh, it depends on the value. Make sure the value in `date` column is a date type else it will fail converting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from tbl_Details WHERE Month(cast(date as Date)) = 2
Or 
Select * from tbl_Details WHERE Month(cast(date as Date)) = 2 and Year(cast(date as Date))=2016
Or
Select * from tbl_Details WHERE Format(cast(date as Date),'yyyy-MM') = '2016-02'
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Tells me you have some bad data,  Thus the reason dates as dates.